# asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator disabling events on code behind

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with framework 3.5 and Ajax Control Toolkit .NET 3.5.

I working on a asp.net web forms website.

On a form I have this: a textbox, an imagebutton, a button, a calendar and a requiredfieldvalidator:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <p>
        <br />
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:Label id="Label3" runat="server">Date</asp:Label>
                        <asp:textbox id="txtInitialDate" runat="server" Width="75px" MaxLength="10"></asp:textbox>

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBegin" 
            ImageUrl="~/images/Icon1.jpeg" runat="server"
                                AlternateText="" Height="24px" Width="24px"   />

        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="txtInitialDate"
        PopupPosition="BottomLeft" PopupButtonID="imgBegin"
        >
        </asp:CalendarExtender>

        <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtInitialDate"
                            Display="Dynamic"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

<asp:button id="Button2" runat="server" Text="Send" onclick="Button2_Click"></asp:button>
</asp:Content>
```

code behind:

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
Button2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:" + Button2.ClientID + ".disabled=true;"     + "javascript:" + Button2.ClientID + ".value='Processing.';" + this.GetPostBackEventReference(Button2) + ";");
base.OnInit(e);
}


protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string a = "some_value";
}
```

The interaction here is that the user clicks on the ImageButton, the calendar shows, the user clicks on a date and then hits the button.

The problem:

If I run the website and click on the ImageButton first and pick a date, then when the button is clicked no events are fired.

But if I comment the code of the validator:

```
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtInitialDate"
                            Display="Dynamic"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
```

Then the events are fired correctly.

I want to be able to use the requiredfieldvalidator, but I don't want it to create conflict with the button

Why is this happening and How can I solve this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CausesValidation=False` in the image button markup:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBegin" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/images/Icon1.jpeg" runat="server"  Height="24px" Width="24px" />
```

You can add that javascript for `Button2` in the markup also (instead of `OnInit` code-behind). Just use `OnclientClick` attribute in the `Button2` mark up

Comment: Thanks! What I did was to remove the OnInit event, and I placed the OnInit event code on the Button2_Click code behind event. The code from OnInit event had to be modified a little so it could run on the code behind Button2_Click event. Thanks again!